# How do I use Atan2?

Tags: c#

I need help with a homework assignment involving atan2 in c#. But whatever I do I keep getting the incorrect answer. Could you please educate me on atan2 and how to use it along with telling me what exactly do I type? This is what I have done

This is all the code I have done

```
            float deltaX = point2X - point1X;
            float deltaY = point2Y - point1Y;
            float distanceSquared = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
            float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(distanceSquared);
            float raidantAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
            float angle = raidantAngle * 180 / (float)Math.PI;
            Console.WriteLine(distance + " " + angle);
```

[Image of the answer/the angle im trying to figure out]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/195mk.png

As you can see, The answer is -135 degrees but I keep on getting 45 degrees

Comment: Are you starting the circle from the correct position (i.e. where do you think 0 degrees is)?

Comment: ^, because 135 + 45 = 180

Comment: What are your input values for point1X, point2X, point1Y and point2Y?

Comment: Im not sure where or how do find the location of correct position

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing point1 and point2? [Because your code correctly returns -135 if you use the right points](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/4fxgcI)

Comment: oh yes, thankyou I was mixing them up

Answer (score 1):

You are [passing arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-6.0) in the wrong order.

It's `atan2(y, x)` not `(x, y)`.